# Nullable generic reference type

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have the following (working) service implemented using C#8, but with nullable reference types disabled:

```cs
public class Foo { }

public interface IFooService
{
    Task<T> Get<T>() where T : Foo;
}

public FooService : IFooService
{
    async Task<T> IFooService.Get<T>() { /* returns either a valid Foo implementation or null */ }
}
```

I tried to enable C#8 nullable reference types, but can't seem to get rid of errors or warnings, whatever I do. The new interface type is:

```cs
public interface IFooService
{
    // T IS nullable AND a reference type.
    // There is no ambiguity as of 'T?' meaning here, because it can't be a struct.
    Task<T?> Get<T>() where T : Foo;
}
```

When I use the following implementation:

```cs
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    async Task<T?> IFooService.Get<T>() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I get the error:

```
'FooService' does not implement interface member 'IFooService.Get<T>()'
```

Which I don't understand because the signatures in the interface and in the implementation are exactly the same.

However, when I implement the interface as this (which is the signature Visual Studio's auto-implementation generates):

```cs
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    async Task<T> IFooService.Get<T>() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
Nullability of reference types in return type doesn't match implemented member 'Task<T?> IFooService.Get<T>()'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the generic constraint to your implementation:

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    async Task<T?> IFooService.Get<T>() where T : class
    {
        /* ... */ 
    }
}
```

It's interesting how Visual Studio doesn't add the `T?` to the implementation it generates. I suspect this is a bug in the editor.

You mention that your type constriant is actually against a `Foo`. This means your code would look like this:

```
public class Foo
{
}

public interface IFooService
{
    // T IS nullable AND a reference type.
    // There is no ambiguity as of 'T?' meaning here, because it can't be a struct.
    Task<T?> Get<T>() where T : Foo;
}

public class FooService : IFooService
{
    async Task<T?> IFooService.Get<T>() where T : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The type constraint is on the interface, but on the implemetation you  can't specify an actual type name, but you can indicate it has to be a class.

Comment: Normally you _cannot_ specify constraints for explicit interface implementations, right? Is this something new in C# 8?

Comment: Ow. I simplified the sample a little bit too much: the interface's generic type constraint is actually `where T : Foo` (which is a class), not `where T : class` (I updated the question). However I can't specify the generic type constraint `where T : Foo` in the implementing class (forbidden by the compiler)... I have to put `where T : class`. This is very counter-intuitive. How come the compiler can't infer the class constraint from the interface?

Comment: @Sweeper Correct. Some constraints (`class` and `struct`) can be repeated in an explicit interface implementation to disambiguate the meaning of `T?` in C# 8. `T?` used to only mean type `Nullable<T>`, but now it can also mean type `T`.